# Connection in the pullback bundle induced by an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $M, \tilde M$ be Riemannian manifolds and $f: M \rightarrow \tilde M$ be an immersion. I have seen that given the Levi-Civita connection $\tilde \nabla$ on $M$, one naturally obtains a connection $\hat \nabla$ in the pullback bundle $f^* T \tilde M$ over $M$. Indeed, for any $Z \in \Gamma(T \tilde M)$ and any $X \in \Gamma(TM)$, we put:
$$ \hat\nabla_X (f^* Z):= \tilde\nabla_{f_* X}(Z) $$
This definition makes sense because a conneciton only depends on the pointwise value of the lower argument, so it doesn't have to be the case that $f_* X$ is a well defined vector **field**, as long as it gives a vector for each point of $M$.

However, I have seen the following notation, which I am trying to make sense of:
$$ \hat\nabla_X (f_* Y), \quad X, Y \in \Gamma(TM)$$
How do I make sense of this? $f_* Y$ is not defined outside the image of $f$, so to apply the connection to it, we would have to pick an extension to a vector field on $\tilde M$, but since the connection $\tilde\nabla$ depends on the value of a vector field on an open set around a point, what guarantees that the result would be independent of the extension?

EDIT: I am now thinking that my question amounts to this: How can we see $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ as a section of $f^* T\tilde M$ (as we intuitively think we should be able to), under the obstruction that $f_* X$ is not a section of $T \tilde M$?

Comment: No, this makes sense only if suitable assumptions on $f$ and $X$ hold. The reason, as you say, is that otherwise the value depends on how you extend $f_*Y$.

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand, we should be able to see $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ as a section of $f^* T \tilde M$, no? Otherwise how can you even define the second normal form for an immersed submanifold into a Riemannian manifold (that's what the text I'm reading is trying to do)?

Comment: In that case $f$ is an immersion, which does imply the answer is independent of the extension.

Comment: Oops. I read this too quickly. In fact, no assumption on $f$ or extension of $Y$ is needed at all. A rather technical explanation is here (scroll down to the section on the pullback of a connection): https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/04/01/PullbackConnection.html. An important point understanding what section of the pullback bundle are.